# MYSQL add index - not adding index?

Tags: mysql, amazon-aurora

I'm adding an index into MySQL 5.7 Aurora for a large table 800GB.
I have on index on it that worked find but when i apply an index on another varchar(255) column it runs for over 10 hours, no error message and i log back in check table and there is no index on it.

I have tried in workbench queries.

```
ALTER TABLE `DataSets`.`companies` 
ADD INDEX `website` (`website` ASC),
```

and

```
CREATE INDEX website ON DataSets.companies(website);
```

They just run and noting happens.

How can i debug and solve this?

Comment: *They just run and noting happens.* Most likely, you just didn't wait for the query to be completed.

Comment: No. i see it running under show processes for 10-17 hours multiple times, the next day i log in to check and no active process and no index..

Answer (score 0):

Since you have 800GB worth of data, MySQL tries to read that data and builds a secondary index with B+tree (key = `website`, value = array of `PRIMARY KEY`), it usually takes hours to days to build such a large index.